# Regex selecting the last 6 numbers of

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am a noob at regex and i've been trying to select 6 numbers from within a file and then replace those 6 numbers with the same numbers plus , new line (making a CSV obviously).

Anyway sample data is simply nonsense like this:

```
fafksadjlkgtjafglkj210000adsfaklgjadklgjag3600001skfjaklaj093i393593390000002sadfljafkjgakjgasafksadjlkgtjafglkj£94.00 489438adsfaklgjadklgjag7700001skfjaklaj093i393593390000002ssafksa djlkgtjafglkj000000adsfaklgjadklgjag0000001skfj aklaj093i393593£39.00900002ssafksadjlk gtjafglkj000000adsfaklgjadklgjag0000001skfjaklaj093i3935£933.90000002s
```

Note some of the numbers are attached to currency values as well (and some are next to it but contain a space before hand) but the end will always be 6 numbers (consider them to be random as I can't see a pattern).

So I basically need to select strings matching numerics that are six digits long or longer, if longer then it just uses the last 6 digits.

Then I will replace it with itself and a comma and new line.

I hope that makes sense, i've tried a few things without success..

Thanks, edit the closest I have is:

```
(\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
```

Comment: is this six number including the decimal? or the last 6.

basically in this example is it 933.900 OR 000002

Comment: no the six won't include the decimal so the monetary amount will be £10.00123456 or £99.99654321 I need to identify the last six so I can break it off onto a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Find what:` text field, type in `(\d{6})(\D)`. In the `Replace with:` text field, type in `$1\r\n$2`. Make sure that the regular expression radio button is selected. For your input, that should yield this:

```
fafksadjlkgtjafglkj210000
adsfaklgjadklgjag3600001
skfjaklaj093i393593390000002
sadfljafkjgakjgasafksadjlkgtjafglkj£94.00 489438
adsfaklgjadklgjag7700001
skfjaklaj093i393593390000002
ssafksa djlkgtjafglkj000000
adsfaklgjadklgjag0000001
skfj aklaj093i393593
£39.00900002
ssafksadjlk gtjafglkj000000
adsfaklgjadklgjag0000001
skfjaklaj093i3935£933.90000002
s
```

Comment: Thanks, this was so close I was able to edit it to exactly my requirements.  That'll save me a bunch of effort and makes my datasets much more useable...thanks, also plus one for thorough explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
\d{6}(?=\D*$)
```

Read more about [anchors here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Answer (score 0):

> i've been trying to select 6 numbers from within a file and then replace those 6 numbers with the same numbers plus , new line

So you're basically trying to do this, right?:

Find:

```
(\d{6})(\D)
```

Replace:

```
\1\n\2
```

[**[Online example]**](http://regex101.com/r/uI6fS3)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `(\d{6,})(?:\D*)$`
Replace with: `$1,\n`